# Access File Properties and then copy files to folder (C#)

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and want to write a simple program in C#. I will be using VS Express to compile my code.

Goal:

I want to write a program that will search within a directory for all files that were created by a particular author.  (Author is found by right clicking the file, opening properties, selecting the details tab and there is a field called Author with a name next to it).  If the Author is the specified author I'm searching for, then I want it to copy the file to a new folder.

The end goal will be that all files created by this particular author will be in one folder.

Is there an easy way to create this program using a windows forms application in VS express? I was thinking you click a button, a message box appears that you select the directory you want, then another message box appears and asks which author you want to search for.  Then a third message box appears asking where you want to save the new folder to.  then the program does everything else.

Any help pointing me in the correct direction to write a program like this, or providing code would be greatly apprecaited.  thank you.

Comment: I think you need to do some COM interop. Specifically try googling for OleDocumentProperties and C#. I think that should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

http://wiki.terrasynq.net/tutorials/c-add-and-edit-ntfs-custom-properties/

It shows how to use OleDocumentProperties to read and edit properties.

Comment: link-only answers are frowned upon around here.  maybe you can better summarize what's at the link